# Initialize benchmark in criterion and exclude initialization time from results

Tags: haskell, haskell-criterion

I need to benchmark some code inside `IO`, and criterion supports that pretty well. But I want to perform few initialization steps (different for each benchmark). The naive approach:

```
main = defaultMain
  [ bench "the first" $ do
      initTheFirst
      theFirst
      cleanUpTheFirst
  , bench "the second" $ do
      initTheSecond
      theSecond
      cleanUpTheSecond
  ]
```

But it performs initialization and cleanup for every benchmark run (100 times by default) and includes initialization time to final results. Is it possible to exclude initialization time?

ADDED:
The code uses global state (mongodb actually), so I can't prepare two initial states simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three real options I can see here. Either initialize and cleanup before and after:

```
main = do
  initTheFirst
  initTheSecond

  defaultMain
    [ bench "the first" theFirst
    , bench "the second" theSecond
    ]

  cleanUpTheFirst
  cleanUpTheSecond
```

Or, if that isn't possible, also benchmark your cleanup and initialization processes and modify your benchmark times accordingly.

Alternatively, you could forego using the provided `defaultMain` and instead roll your own using the lower-level functions provided by Criterion.

Comment: AFAIU, the requirement is to cleanup in between the two benchmarks.

Comment: Hence my second option. If there is legitimately enough global state here that `initTheFirst` is necessary before every `theFirst >> cleanUpTheFirst`, I don't see an alternative to one of these two options while still using defaultMain.

Comment: I can't use the first option unfortunately. Re the second option: do you mean just substitute run time of init/cleanup pair from total run time? Will not it invalidate results because of variations in init/cleanup run time (it is heavy)?

Comment: Custom main instead of the default one seems to be the way to go. Thanks for idea!

Comment: @argiopeweb Could you please add a note about custom main as the 3d option into your answer? (I don't know how I missed the possibility to create custom main... but it is exactly what I need, works like a charm)

Comment: Done. I'd love to see your results. Any chance you could make it available here or as a GitHub Gist?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using custom main as suggested by argiopeweb:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Concurrent
import Criterion
import Criterion.Config
import Criterion.Monad
import Criterion.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = myMain [
  (initTheFirst, theFirst),
  (initTheSecond, theSecond)
  ]

initTheFirst :: IO ()
initTheFirst = do
  putStrLn "initializing the first"
  threadDelay 1000000

theFirst :: Benchmark
theFirst = bench "the first" $ do
  return () :: IO ()

initTheSecond :: IO ()
initTheSecond = do
  putStrLn "initializing the second"
  threadDelay 1000000

theSecond :: Benchmark
theSecond = bench "the second" $ do
  return () :: IO ()

myMain :: [(IO (), Benchmark)] -> IO ()
myMain benchmarks = withConfig defaultConfig $ do
  env <- measureEnvironment
  forM_ benchmarks $ \(initialize, benchmark) -> do
    liftIO $ initialize
    runAndAnalyse (const True) env benchmark
```

The output:

```
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 1.723574 us (320001 iterations)
found 1888 outliers among 319999 samples (0.6%)
  1321 (0.4%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 43.45580 ns (13 iterations)
found 2 outliers among 13 samples (15.4%)
  2 (15.4%) high severe
initializing the first

benchmarking the first
mean: 7.782388 ns, lb 7.776217 ns, ub 7.790563 ns, ci 0.950
std dev: 36.01493 ps, lb 29.29834 ps, ub 52.51021 ps, ci 0.950
initializing the second

benchmarking the second
mean: 7.778543 ns, lb 7.773192 ns, ub 7.784518 ns, ci 0.950
std dev: 28.85100 ps, lb 25.59891 ps, ub 32.85481 ps, ci 0.950
```

You can see that `init*` functions are called only once and don't affect benchmarks results.